# svg scale rect so that corners overlap

Tags: svg, scale, transformation

I have a rect with top left corner at (x1,y1), rendered with svg.
When I rescale this rect, I want the top left corner of the new rect, to be at the same coordinate (x1,y1). Is there a Formula to translate the resized Rect, so that this can happen?

Even better, is there a more general approach, so that the rect can overlap with the corner of my choice?

[image: Corners should overlap, when rescaling]

EDIT: I added this jsfiddle example I found:
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/VRpYT/5/) .
I have a rect:

```
<rect id="square" x="15" y="15" width="20" height="20" 
style="fill: none; stroke:black" />

<use xlink:href="square" transform="scale(5)" />
```

I want both rects to have the same coordinate (15,15) for their 
topleft corner

Comment: Are you talking about two rects? The new rect being inside of the older rect then scaling until it's top left corner is flush with the bottom right hand corner of the old rect? You haven't made any svg yet to show as an example?

Comment: I editor my post and added the code for my problem

Comment: If you set the `scale(1)` , the big one will scale down to the size of the original and they'd be both at (15, 15) . The side affect of `transform=scaling` is that the coords change accordingly. So if the big rect is scaled down from 5 then divide it's dimensions (200x200) by 10 and it's coordinates + stroke width.(75,75) by 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you wanted the big rect to stay that size or if you wanted to scale down, so I have two solutions for you.

1. The simple way of matching both rects' coords is to scale down the big one. If you set the scale(1) , the big one will scale down to the size of the original and they'd be both at (15, 15) . The side affect of transform=scaling is that the coords change accordingly. So if the big rect is scaled down from 5 then divide it's dimensions (200x200) by 10 and it's coordinates + stroke width.(75,75) by 5.
2. The other way is if your intentions were to keep the size of the big rect at 200x200. You can move it with `transform=translate(-12.5,-12.5)` The reason why it's not (-15,-15) is because it's stroke is 5px wide.

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/QNPPoZ?editors=1100)

Both solutions are on the demo #1 is commented out.

Comment: Thanks, #2 was what i was looking for! Could you give me a brief explanation or a formula, why you the translate value is -12.5?

Comment: When it was scaled(5), that also scaled the stroke width to 5px (1px is default). If you deal with positioning anything that has a border, you must take half of the border's width into measuring the length needed from the edge of the viewport. So (-15, -15), is the logical coords **IF** the border or stroke was still 1px. Of course, it's not exact because by that logic it would be (-14.5, -14.5). Or maybe it actually is but not discernible... But what you can take from this is this: trial and error. My first attempt was (-15, -15) and it was not even close, so it took me 2 more adjustments :P

Answer (score 0):

Use your scaled element in a `g` element and add to this element `transform="translate(15 15)"`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
 <defs>
  <rect id="square" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" style="fill: none; stroke:black" />
 </defs>
 <use x="15" y="15" xlink:href="#square" />
 <g  transform="translate(15 15)">
  <use xlink:href="#square" transform="scale(5)" />
 </g>
</svg>
```